# rtpproxy is not listening at 7722

Tags: ubuntu, rtp

My retproxy is not listening on 7722 port .I have mentioned this in modparam("rtpproxy","rtpproxy_sock","udp:127.0.0.1:7722")

modparam("rtpproxy","rtpproxy_sock","unix:/var/run/rtpproxy/rtpproxy.sock")

also I have enable attributes on /etc/default/rtpproxy

Can anyone help ?

Comment: What do your logs say ?

Comment: There is a blank screen shows nothing about logs . Also in /var/run there is no RTPproxy.sock . What to do ?

Comment: did you find a solution to this - i have the same problem